# Is there a way to fix these Mesa dependecy issues?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libglapi-mesa:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libegl-mesa0:amd64:
 libegl-mesa0:amd64 depends on libglapi-mesa; however:
  Package libglapi-mesa:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libegl-mesa0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglx-mesa0:amd64:
 libglx-mesa0:amd64 depends on libglapi-mesa (= 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2); however:
  Package libglapi-mesa:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: error processing package libglx-mesa0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libosmesa6:amd64:
 libosmesa6:amd64 depends on libglapi-mesa (= 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2); however:
  Package libglapi-mesa:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libosmesa6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 depends on libglapi-mesa; however:
  Package libglapi-mesa:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 depends on libglx-mesa0; however:
  Package libglx-mesa0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving uncoNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   nfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcogl20:amd64:
 libcogl20:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-glx; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcogl20:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-cogl-1.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-cogl-1.0:amd64 depends on libcogl20 (>= 1.21.2); however:
  Package libcogl20:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-cogl-1.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-coglpango-1.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0:amd64 depends on gir1.2-cogl-1.0 (= 1.22.2-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package gir1.2-cogl-1.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-coglpango-1.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcogl-pango20:amd64:
 libcogl-pango20:amd64 depends on libcogl20 (>= 1.17.4); however:
  Package libcogl20:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcogl-pango20:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcogl-path20:amd64:
 libcogl-path20:amd64 depends on libcogl20 (>= 1.18.0); however:
  Package libcogl20:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcogl-path20:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglapi-mesa:amd64
 libegl-mesa0:amd64
 libglx-mesa0:amd64
 libosmesa6:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 libcogl20:amd64
 gir1.2-cogl-1.0:amd64
 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0:amd64
 libcogl-pango20:amd64
 libcogl-path20:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Been trying to remedy this dependency hell, tried the usual recommended gamut. Can anybody tell me what perhaps is going wrong - and yes, I know it's probably *right* in front of my face.